# UseState to update multiple properties in object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using destructuring, I can update multiple object properties with one function:

```
const [serverRequest, setServerRequest] = useState({ ID: "", RAM: "", CPU: "", appInstaller: [{}] });

return (
  <div className="App">
    <label className="label">ID</label>
    <input
      className="input"
      type="text"
      name="ID"
      value={serverRequest?.ID}
      onChange={e =>
        setServerRequest({
          ...serverRequest,
          ID: e.target.value
        })
      }
    />
    <input
      className="input"
      type="text"
      name="RAM"
      value={serverRequest?.RAM}
      onChange={e =>
        setServerRequest({
          ...serverRequest,
          RAM: e.target.value
        })
      }
    />
  </div>
);
```

However, I'd like to do this on a object array. How can I do this?

Using

```
const [serverRequests, setServerRequests] = useState([{ ID: "", RAM: "", CPU: "", appInstaller: [{}] }]);
const [selectedServer, setSelectedServer] = useState(0);

onChange={e =>
  setServerRequests({
    ...serverRequests[selectedServer],
    ID: e.target.value
  })
}
```

Will convert the array into a single object on the first change, and then remove all other properties on the second change.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
onChange={e =>
  setServerRequests(oldValue => {
    // first spread value
    oldValue[selectedServer] = {
      ...oldValue[selectedServer],
      ID: e.target.value
    }

    // and now spread and return array
    return [...oldValue]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={e =>
  setServerRequests({
    ...serverRequests[selectedServer],
    ID: e.target.value
  })
}
```

This means "set `serverRequests` with this ID, and spread `serverRequests[selectedServer]` inside". So yes, it becomes one single object. to avoidthat, you need to spread your previous state before:

`setServerRequests({...serverRequests, otherChange: otherValue})`.

Now if you need to change jsut one object from `serverRequests`, you need to create a copy of it, edit the object you want to change and then spread it inside your `setServerRequests`. Something like :

```
onchange = () => {
 const state = Object.assign({}, serverRequests); // or lodash clonedeep
 const objIndexToEdit = // get index of the item you want to changes
 state[objIndexToEdit] = // your changed obj (do it as you wish, just giving an example)
 setServerRequests({...state});
}
```